# Detect and react to custom keyboard input events

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

How should I go about listening to keypresses, keydowns, and keyups of, say, <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>?

From the documentation of [ScreenSpaceEventHandler(element).setInputAction(action, type, modifier)](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ScreenSpaceEventHandler.html#setInputAction), it follows that `type` and `modifier` must be of types [ScreenSpaceEventType](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ScreenSpaceEventType.html) and [KeyboardEventModifier](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/KeyboardEventModifier.html) respectively, which amount to a rather restricted set of events available for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScreenSpaceEventHandler` is only for input events that involve screen space:  mouse, touch, and pointer events.  For raw keyboard events like <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, just use JavaScript native [keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) such as [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown), [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress), etc.  You don't need Cesium's help to receive these events.

You will, however, need to apply a `tabindex` to the Cesium canvas, to enable it to receive the input focus:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var canvas = viewer.canvas;
canvas.setAttribute('tabindex', '0'); // needed to put focus on the canvas
```

You can find a complete working example of this in the [Cesium Camera Tutorial](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Camera%20Tutorial.html&label=Showcases).  Click on the globe itself, and then use <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to move the camera.

Comment: What is the difference between `viewer.canvas` and `viewer.scene.canvas`?

Comment: The scene "owns" the canvas.  The viewer's `canvas` property is just a shortcut to the scene's canvas.  For that matter, the `scene` property itself is a shortcut too:  The viewer owns a CesiumWidget (and several other widgets), and the CesiumWidget owns the scene, and the scene owns the canvas.